# Execute MySQL Select passthrough from a subform and send output recordset to a parent form

Tags: vba, ms-access, subform

I manage a Microsoft Access 2019 Database (owned by a customer) with a form (named *Mainform*) whose recordset source is a MySQL passthrough query (*SELECT * FROM table_on_mysql_db*); each recordset (shown directly on opening *Mainform*) is only readable and it has three fields: one of them, *description*, contains text.

On double clicking on *description* field, a small sized subform (name *Subform*, containing one textvalue field named *keywordDescr*, plus an *OK* button and a *Cancel* button) pops up.

If I enter some words in *keywordDescr* (i.e. *anyword*) and press *OK*, the following passthrough query

**SELECT * FROM table_on_mysql_db WHERE description LIKE '%anyword%'**

is being called and the resultset ouput must be displayed in *Mainform* (*Subform* still remains opened); unfortunately, the *Mainform* content is not updated accordingly to the above MySQL filtered query.

The following is the VBA code called on clicking the *OK* button in *Subform* (OK is the label and the button name is *button_search_description*):

```vb
Private sub button_search_description_Click()
  on Error goto ErrDescr

  Dim qdfc as DAO.QueryDef
  Dim qryPT as String
  Dim ODBC_STRING as String
  Dim kwd as String

  kwd = Me.keywordDescr
  kwd = Replace(kwd, "*", "%") '(the customer is still used to entering Access wildcard rather than MySQL wildcard!)
  kwd = Replace(kwd, "'", "\'")

  ODBC_STRING = "ODBC;DSN=MY_DSN_NAME"  ' it works!  

  qryPT = "SELECT * FROM table_on_mysql_db WHERE description LIKE '" & kwd & "'"
  
  DoCmd.setWarnings = false
  Set qdfc = DBEngine(0)(0).CreateQueryDef("")

  With qdfc
     .Connect = ODBC_STRING
     .SQL = qryPT
     .ReturnsRecords = True
     Me.Parent.RecordSource = qryPT   
  End With

  Set qdfc = nothing
  DoCmd.setWarnings = true
  
ErrDescr:
  Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean a subform or a smaller normal form popping up?

Comment: If you run the code after disabling the `on Error goto ErrDescr` and `DoCmd.setWarnings = false` lines, does Access tell you anything useful?

Comment: If this is a pop up form, then it you'll need to use the form.recordsource, rather than me.parent, it should be me.parent.form i think also if using this approach.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav popup

Comment: @HansUp
I get *Error 2452: The expression you entered has invalid to the Parent property*

Comment: @Nathan_Sav as my customer required right now, two of the three fields extracted by SELECT are:
`CONCAT(TRIM(table_on_mysql_db.name1), '  ', NVL(TRIM(table_on_mysql_db.name2), '')) as fullnameA,
CONCAT(TRIM(table_on_mysql_db.name3), '  ', NVL(TRIM(table_on_mysql_db.name4), '')) as fullnameB
`

where NVL is a MySQL function which replaces *name2* (*name4*) with an empty string if  *name2* (*name4*) is NULL, as well as CONCAT is a mysql aggregate function....so, replacing *me.parent* with *Me.Recordsource*, Access tells that **CONCAT function is not recognized**

Comment: @m3t4l If the form named "Subform" is not an actual [subform](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-ddf3822f-8aba-49cb-831a-1e74d6f5f06b#bmsubformbasics), it has no parent form --- so `Me.Parent` is not valid.

Comment: @HansUp is on the right track.  You're not working with a subform embedded in your main form, but rather a popup form.  Also you don't need a querydef at all here.  After you set qryPT = "SELECT..." all you need to do is set your main form's RecordSource property to that string, e.g. if your form is named "MainForm" then Forms!MainForm.RecordSource = qryPT should be all you need.

Comment: @HansUp, from what I have been reading, VBA is needed to modify pass-through query object to include filter parameters if you want the processing to be done by the MySQL backend.

Comment: I am confused. OP code shows pulling data from a table so how can there be fields constructed with functions as shown in comment? Does MySQL allow calculated fields in table? It is possible to set RecordSource to an SQL statement that refers to a PTQ as source `SELECT * FROM PTQName;`. But why bother setting RecordSource with code? Use code to modify the PTQ but just set RecordSource in form design to either the PTQ name or the SQL statement I proposed.

Comment: And it really doesn't make sense to modify query object and then set form RecordSource to that same SQL statement. Apologies to @Hansup, I referenced wrong username in my earlier comment.

Comment: @deluxeinformation
unfortunately *mainform* still has another passthrough MySQL query as recordsource, without parameter...what I need is to change recordsource as PT MySQL query with an input parameter and, according to the MS Access Support, the only way to execute such PT query is by VBA code, with a customed popup input parameter

Answer (score 1):

Really doesn't make sense to modify query object and then set form RecordSource to that same SQL statement.

In design view, set form RecordSource to pass-through query object name or an SQL statement that uses pass-through query as source: `SELECT * FROM PTQname;`. Use code to modify pass-through query object to change parameters but don't change form RecordSource.

Comment: as I replied to deluxeinformation, mainform still has a filtered PT query (select) as a recordsource, set by the form property pane and not in the code. That said, you mean that I only need to change the PT query without reassigning the mainform recordsource?

Comment: That is my thought. Shouldn't hurt to test.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this approach but you will likely need to follow up with a MainForm.Requery as your form will be unaware you've changed the PT query behind the scenes.  Also when you close your MainForm, you might want to reset your PT query's SQL to whatever it was when you opened the form so the next time you open your form it is not filtered to the previous user's criteria.  This maintenance overhead is why I would prefer to leave the PT query alone and simply filter the results that come out of it at run time.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little confusing to me what you're trying to do here but as I understand it you have a pure MySQL query (PTQName) that is the recordsource of a form (MainForm) when it is first opened.  Right now this is a passthrough query defined in Access but not in MySQL.  Then you want to be able to open a pop up form to filter the results you get from PTQName in MainForm.  What I would do first is take the code for PTQName and create an actual view in MySQL Workbench from this (for example, call it "MyView").  Then link that view into your Access database.  Access will treat this MySQL view as just another linked table.  Set the recordsource of your MainForm to the name of this view so when it opens it displays records from your view.  When you want to filter the records shown in your MainForm using your popup form, either use MainForm's Filter and FilterOn properties, or set MainForm's recordsource = "select * from MyView where ...".  I am not seeing a need to even use a pass-through query here, let alone modify its SQL at runtime. But if I am misunderstanding please let me know!

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful reply. Maybe I chose the wrong solution instead of a MySQL View...the problem is that the MS Access DB under my management is used by a customer unwilling to change to a web intranet solution (that'd be easier to manage to me), and prefers using MS Access front end with a MySQL database. After the last Microsoft Update, some ODBC connection broke up, so I chose to turn the queries into passthrough queries as a workaround. No problem with unfiltered PTqueries or wired filters, but the problem is with a PT query requiring an input parameter

Comment: In your example it seemed you just wanted to filter the results coming from your passthrough query ("SELECT * FROM table_on_mysql_db WHERE...") The ideal solution is to use a view but if you can't, the next most versatile solution is to create a passthrough query and set it as form recordsource (not "select * from PTQuery" but just PTQuery).  Then modify the PTQuery SQL at runtime as your initial code did and @June7 answered, and issue a MainForm.Requery.  But keep in mind this approach is a hassle because the changes you make to PTQuery using qdfc.SQL = "my SQL string" are persistent.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved the problem; @deluxeinformation gave me the right track, but I also wish to thank tho other users who gave me useful hints.

I defined a view on MySQL database named *View_list*, then set *View_list* as *Mainform* record source and, on *Mainform* load, the filtered PT query *SELECT * FROM View_list WHERE F1* is executed, where *F1* is the default filter where *Mainform* is loaded.

Similar PT query but with a different filter is being called clicking on the *OK* button in the *Subform*; the VBA code bound to this event is the following (*kwd* is the value entered in the input text *keywordDescr* of the subform *Subform*):

```
qryPT = "SELECT * FROM View_list WHERE description LIKE '" & kwd & "'"

With qdfc
     .Connect = ODBC_STRING
     .SQL = qryPT
     .ReturnsRecords = True
     Forms!Mainform.RecordSource = qryPT   
End With
```